# How many episodes were there where a transporter accident was an integral part of the plot?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-transporter

In all iterations of Star Trek, (TOS, TNG, DS9, VOY, ENT and the movies) how many transporter accidents or incidents, integral to the plot, have there been?

Comment: Would that be any episode with any transporter problem, or would it have to be central to that episode? Do the movies count?

Comment: @Politank-Z central to the episode

Comment: Off the top of my head, several per show. Tuvix. The one with Thomas Riker. Realm of Fear, the Next Phase, all of the alt universe ones like the Enemy Within, Rascals, Drone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the criteria that an accident must occur and that it must be integral to the plot (e.g mentioned repeatedly or main plot driver), there are surprisingly few "transporter accident" episodes, only one or two per show.

For completeness, I've also lumped in those episodes where **intentional abuse** of the transporter occurs as the main plot driver

### TOS

**[The Enemy Within](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Enemy_Within_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Life creation**
**[Mirror, Mirror](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Travel to Mirror Universe**

---

### TNG

**[Rascals](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rascals_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Age regression**
**[Realm of Fear](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Realm_of_Fear_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Personnel trapped in matter stream**
**[Second Chances](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Chances_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Life creation**
**[Data's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%27s_Day)** - Transporter abuse: **Faked death**
**[The Next Phase](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Next_Phase_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Personnel trapped out of phase**

---

### Voy

**[Drone](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Drone_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Life creation**
**[Tuvix](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tuvix_(episode))** - Transport accident: **Life creation / Moral dilemma**

---

### DS9

**[Our Man Bashir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Our_Man_Bashir_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Personnel trapped in buffer**
**[Through the Looking-Glass](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode))** - Transporter abuse: **Travel to Mirror Universe**
**[Shattered Mirror](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shattered_Mirror_(episode))** - Transporter abuse: **Travel to Mirror Universe**
**[The Emperor's New Cloak](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Cloak_(episode))** - Transporter abuse: **Travel to Mirror Universe**
**[Field of Fire](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Field_of_Fire_(episode))** - Transporter abuse: **Murder**

---

### ENT

**[Daedelus](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Daedalus_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Death in transit**
**[Vanishing point](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vanishing_Point_(episode))** - Transporter accident: **Trapped in buffer**

---

### Movies

[Star Trek: The Motion Picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture) - Transporter accident: **Death in transit x 2**

Comment: So the answer is 16?

Comment: @user14111 - The figure is debatable. For example, is the transporter accident in ST: TMP plot integral or merely a device to explain the return of Spock. Does Data's Day count since there was no real transporter accident, etc etc.

Comment: So you haven't answered the question. It asks for the value of a certain integer.

Comment: @user14111 - As I've said, the major problem is that any numerical value would be meaningless without more closely defining the original question.

Comment: you should add ENT: Vanishing Point too as the whole episode was about the transport cycle being disrupted: therefore not a normal transport

Comment: @Matt - You're not wrong.

Comment: Plot-smlot. How many (non-time-travely-wobbly, nor Q-fooed) fatalities in total due to transporter accidents?

Comment: @Mazura - The transporter is more likely to create life than take it.

Comment: What about TNG: Relics - Certainly, the transporter is being used for a purpose other than the intended one there.

Comment: @RDFozz - Would you say it was *integral* to the plot? It was explained away very shortly after it occurred...

Comment: @Valorum - Well, it is the means via which Scotty reaches the TNG era. Without that, you don't really have an episode.

Comment: @RDFozz - Would you describe it as an accident? If we're including that, we should probably include [VOY: Counterpoint](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Counterpoint_(episode)) since that's also about people intentionally hiding in the transport buffer

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as an accident - however, I would describe it as an incident. Whether Counterpoint counts or not is more problematic - when Scotty tried it, he wasn't sure if it would work, or how well. While it's not a standard usage, the usage in Voyager seems to be within the known capacities of the transporter. There's some risk involved (I believe the Doctor indicates that repeated usage will ultimately cause/exacerbate health problems), but it's not an out-and-out-life-or-death-toss-of-the-coin gamble each time they do it.

Comment: @RDFozz - I remain unconvinced. There's lots of things the transporters were used for that don't fit the definition of "standard use".

Comment: @Valorum - I'll agree that different people may have different interpretations of "accidents or incidents", and that yours isn't entirely unreasonable. Everyone entitled to the own opinion, no matter how "wrong" it may be (I leave it to the reader to pick which opinion, if any, is "right") :-)